# Install stackoverflow like software on my site

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is Stack Overflow open source? If so - where can I get the source code?

If not - I see some people using it: http://answers.unity3d.com how did they get it?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16780/stacked-an-open-source-implementation-of-stackoverflow-com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your own "Stack Overflow" from http://stackexchange.com - you can be up and running for free to give the platform a spin.

Comment: Umm.. is there no free options? I mean how did you guys get a hold of it?

Comment: Stack Overflow was the original site, and they developed it. There is no free option available.

Comment: Hm.. methinks I heard them talking about open sourcing it. Or maybe im crazy. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @drozzy: @JeffAtwood (creator and co-founder of Stack Overflow) did pose the question of open-sourcing a while back - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3086/will-open-sourcing-stack-overflow-destroy-our-business-model

Comment: Wow, it seems that question was beaten to death already... well I guess the only way for me to get something like this is to make it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @drozzy: Keep us updated! It's a massive undertaking! :)

Comment: @drozzy: you can also take a look at some open source alternatives listed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Answer (score 2):

See: [Which CMS or other framework should I use to develop a stackoverflow-like site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638/which-cms-or-other-framework-should-i-use-to-develop-a-stackoverflow-like-site)